# Asp.Net Mvc - Find attributes for a given method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to write some extensions for testing and one of the specs I want to run would be based on finding the list of attributes associated with a method (action).

So far, this is the code I use to grab attributes off a method:

```
var homeController = new HomeController();
(controller.GetType().GetMethod(action, parameters)).GetCustomAttributes(false)
```

etc...

or for a controller, something like this (which is more explicit and not reusable)

```
(typeof(HomeController)).GetCustomAttributes(false)
```

So the question is, given I have a generic action of **type ActionResult** example:

```
var actionResult = new HomeController().Index();
```

Is there a way to find the attributes of that instance of the `actionResult` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just have `actionResult` then you don't really have the action method. You just have the result of its execution. Multiple methods can return the same result, for example.

You have to have a reference to the method itself. Your reflection calls should be fine. What do you not like about them?